# Having object send its own delegate a message after its been removed from superview

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have the following method:

```
- (void) okButtonPushed
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(alertViewWillDismiss:)])
    {
        [self.delegate alertViewWillDismiss:self];
    }

    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

It's an OK button on a custom `AlertView` object that when pushed dismisses the alert. I'd like for the delegate to send a message AFTER the alert has been removed from the superview, but obviously this isn't possible since it will be deallocated by then. The only other solution I can think of this is for the superview to keep another pointer to my object, but then everytime I do an alert, I have to implicitly know to make sure to keep another pointer to it. Is there a cleaner way to do this from within my `AlertView` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [willMoveToSuperview:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/willMoveToSuperview%3a) callback (

```
-(void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    if (newSuperview == nil) {    
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(alertViewWillDismiss:)]) {
            [self.delegate alertViewWillDismiss:self];
        }
    }
}
```

It will be called before the view is deallocated, and just *before* it's been truly removed from the superview (with *newSuperview == nil*).

EDIT: If you want it to be just *after* it's been (re)moved – use [didMoveToSuperview:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/didMoveToSuperview)

Comment: Ah that's an interesting solution, thanks. Just of curiosity, but why would I use willMoveToSuperview instead of didMoveToSuperView?

Comment: I ended up implementing with didMoveToSuperView and it seemed to have the same effect. Thanks for the response.

Comment: In my case – I had to get a screenshot of my view before it disappeared, to animate the transition. Cheers!

Comment: Added the did/will diff. to my answer, for future visitor's sake.